# I'm facing the issue mentioned below while displaying the price list for the domains suggested

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

[image]While getting tld's and domain name from enom api I'm getting error as "Unsupported Operand" for particular tld's like "co.in","in.net". Suggest me a solution to solve this.

Find below my controller code

```
   public function domaincheck(Request $request)
  {
        $sld = $request['sld'];
        $tld = $request['tld'];
        $response = file_get_contents('https://reseller.enom.com/interface.asp?command=check&sld='. $sld .'&tld='. $tld .'&uid=decksys&pw=resellpw&responsetype=xml');  
        $data = simplexml_load_string($response);
        $configdata   = json_encode($data);
        $final_data = json_decode($configdata,true);// Use true to get data in array rather than object
        // dd($final_data);
 }
```

The blade code is given below:

```
     <div class="form-group">
     <div class=" col-lg-2"></div>
     <div class="col-lg-8">
         <div class="input-group m-b">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="padding-left:10px; background-color: #999;" class='unclickable'>www</span>
            <input type="text" name="sld" class="form-control" required>
  <span class="input-group-addon">

  <select class="form-control" name="tld" style="width: 100px;">
  <option value="com">com</option>
  <option value="in">in</option>
  <option value="info">info</option>
  <option value="org">org</option>
  <option value="co.in">co.in</option>
  <option value="in.net">in.net</option>
  <option value="net">net</option>
  <option value="biz">biz</option>
      </select>  
      </span>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" >Submit</button>  
      </span>
```

My route is given below:

```
Route::get('/registerdomain','EnomController@domaincheck');
```

Comment: What happens when you change your request lines to this? $sld = $request->input('sld'); $tld = $request->input('tld');

Comment: Still i have the same error....

Comment: Do you get the correct $sld and $tld values when you submit the form? Can you check adding dd($sld, $tld); before the $response = .... line?

Comment: I got an output like this "decksys" "co.in"

Comment: So in which line you get the error? I also suggest you to remove your password from the domaincheck if that's your actual password.

Comment: `@if(isset($result['Domains']['Domain']['Prices']))
                @foreach($result['Domains']['Domain']['Prices'] as $key => $value)         @if($var1 == "Domain not available")
                  @else
                @if($key == "Registration")
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center" style="font-size:25px;padding-top:10px">
                <strong>₹ {{number_format($value * $var)}}</strong>
                   <button class="btn btn-info">Add to Cart</button>
                @endif 
                @endif                 
                @endforeach
              @endif`

Comment: I got an error above code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171981/discussion-between-sharmila-and-can-celik).